# How to invoke amazon service through SOAP

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I need to invoke aws through SOAP by using java.Is there any application that create SOAP request ?. I mean while giving WSDL link it should create a SOAP query and should allow to invoke.i have tried out eclipse addon but it doesnot creating SOAP request..Can any one help...?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any application that create SOAP request ?.

[soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)

> soapUI is a tool for functional testing, mainly of Web Services like SOAP based Web Services and REST Web Services, but also  HTTP based services and JMS Services as well as databases. soapUI is an Open Source tool with a commercial companion, soapUI Pro, with extra functionality for companies with mission critical Web Services. soapUI is being produced by the community as well as the Open Source company eviware.